# How to keep a if else condition for this Ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am getting the following ajax response from backend

```
jsonCallback([])
```

I have got the following code in my Ajax success response

```
success: function(response) {
  if(response!=='[]')
  {
     alert('postive condition');
  }
  else 
  {
    alert('into else condition');
  }
},
```

despite of the condition , why is it always going to the **if conditon** (**Positive conditon** )

Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: You are getting empty array, You can use `response.length == 0`

Comment: @Satpal comment is right

Answer (score 0):

`!==` will expect the result should be same including the codes try to use `!=`.